# Index the content of KV file with Logstash in one document dynamically

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have many properties files with the following structures key = Value , the sample data is  :

```
rejets.cache.temporaire.time=60
data.cache.referentiel.time=10
data.cache.temporaire.time=60
data.cache.getinfos.time=200
```

The input file config :

```
file {
        path => [ "C:/logstash-7.3.1/data/input/data_conf_recette/keyvalue/*" ]

        start_position => beginning
        type => "config_file_kv_recette"
        codec => multiline {
        pattern => "\n"
        what => "previous"
        negate => true
        }
}
```

I want to index this file as a document elasticsearch dynamicaly (the name of the field ) like this :

```
 {
   rejets.cache.temporaire.time:60
   data.cache.referentiel.time:10
   data.cache.temporaire.time:60
    data.cache.getinfos.time:200
  }
```

I used the following configuration but i found in my index each field is indexed in one document ,so in my case i have 4 documents indexed :

```
mutate {
             gsub => [ "message", "[\\\\]r", "esp" ]
             gsub => [ "message", "[\\\\]n", "ace" ]
        }

        ruby {
             code => "begin; event['message'] = event['message'].split(/espace/); rescue Exception; end"
        }

        kv {
            source => "message"
            value_split => "="
            field_split => "\n"
        }

        grok {
                        match => { "message" => "(?<param>[^=]*)=%{GREEDYDATA:value}" }
                }

        if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
                        drop {}
                }

        mutate {
            remove_field => ["message"]
        }
```

How can i make this please ? thanks for Help

Comment: What is your input block? Do your inpu file has one key-value pair per line? Logstash process each line as a single event, you would need to use a codec to aggregate them (multiline, for example), but you need to share your input block and a sample data of your input file.

Comment: i add the input file block

Comment: In your case your multiline plugin conf should use a pattern like this: `^rejets` so that any line that don't start with rejets is joined with the previous one.

Comment: thanks i use that   codec => multiline { pattern => "^loremipsum" negate => true what => previous auto_flush_interval => 1 multiline_tag => "" }